# Calculate sum of a list of variables by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with one key and about 100 numeric rows, one of which is set to key. I would like to create a new variable that contains summation of each numeric rows, grouped by key.

For example, my data right now is

```
ID Count1 Count2 Count3
1   1      3      0
1   3      3      3
2   1      2      1
3   1      1      2
```

What I would like to have is:

```
ID Count1 Count2 Count3
1   4      6      3
2   1      2      1
3   1      1      2
```

I have tried so many ways to get this. I know I can do:

```
Y <- X[, list(Count=sum(Count1), Count2=sum(Count2), Count3=sum(Count3), by = ID]
```

However, I have hundreds of variables, and I only get their names on a list. How should I go about handling this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is a code to generate test data:

```
ID <-c(rep(210, 9), rep(3917,6))
Count1 <- c(1,1,0,1,3,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
Count2 <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
Count3 <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
x <- data.table(ID, Count1, Count2, Count3)
setkey(x, ID)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your test data doesn't match the example you gave, but regardless - you can take advantage of the fact that `data.table()` has an operator named `.SD` for "subset of data. So this should work:

```
x[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ID]
#----
     ID Count Count2 Count3
1:  210    13      5      5
2: 3917     5      5      5
```

This is actually covered in the FAQ: type `vignette("datatable-faq", package="data.table")` or find it [online](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html).

Comment: Gotta love learning R. Definitely values brevity over readability. *Of course* SD means "subset of data". What possible problem could there be using this abbreviation in a statistical analysis language? :)

Answer (score 11):

As a data.table is a data.frame, you can use aggregate for this:

```
> aggregate(. ~ ID, data=x, FUN=sum)
    ID Count1 Count2 Count3
1  210     13      5      5
2 3917      5      5      5
```

Comment: But if you were using a data.table you wouldn't want to.

Comment: Probably not.  `aggregate` takes twice as long.